# Bose-Einstein condensate and nonlinear waves

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, non-linear-systems, bose-einstein-condensate

Can [Bose-Einstein condensate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate) be written as non-linear wave equation (in terms of mean field approximation theory)?
the equation is: [image]

source: http://xxx.tau.ac.il/abs/1308.2288

> What I do understand by the Bose-Einstein condensate is, it is the
>   state of atoms at very low temperatues and at the moment the atoms
>   forget their previous identity. Therefore all the atoms stay in the
>   same quantum state.

Am I right?

Comment: Why is this getting [close votes](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/close/26679)?

Comment: Dont know why but I have not got canonical answer yet  still.

Answer (score 1):

Bose-Einstein condensation is based on the indistinguishability and wave nature of particles, which are both basic concept of quantum mechanics. If you want to define Bose-Einstein condensation in one sentence, you can say it is the occupation of the lowest quantum state of the external potential by a large fraction of bosons forming the system. Particles are assumed to be bosons because only the Bose-Einstein statistics allows an arbitrary large number of particles to occupy one single quantum state.

The equation describing a condensate (or better the wave function of a condensate) is the [Gross-Pitaevskii equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross%E2%80%93Pitaevskii_equation) that is often referred as a non-linear Schroedinger equation.